# How do I stop this install of Office

Tags: installation, microsoft-office

For a few days now, after a boot, I see this error

> **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010**
> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
> Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package `ProPlusrWW.msi` in the box below.

I did have a look at the `Apps and Features` and Office 2010 is installed, but I will not let me uninstall it.  I press Uninstall and I verify the action. But nothing happens.  So I suspect a corrupted install record from when I did have Office 2010 installed (it was a corporate version then).  I purchased my own in 2016.

But I have Office Professional Plus 2016 installed.

How do I stop this from popping up again ?

Comment: Run the [Office 2010 uninstall tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-automatically-9ad57b43-fa12-859a-9cf0-b694637b3b05). At one time you must have had Office 2010 installed, installed Office 2016, and since the 2 Office installations of the same bitness cannot go exist Office 2010 was only partially uninstalled when Office 2016 was installed

Comment: Look in Programs and Features and see if Outlook 2010 is installed. On a reasonable fresh install of Windows Outlook 2016 /365 does not install Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

I looked at `Startup Apps` and found `Microsoft Office Document Cache`.  Not knowing what it was, not really wanting a cache anywhere, I stopped it.

After reboot, no more question.

As suggested by @Ramhound, I ran the [Office 2010 uninstall tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-automatically-9ad57b43-fa12-859a-9cf0-b694637b3b05) to remove the partially uninstalled Office 2010.

Comment: If you stopped the error you may no longer be interested in fixing it.  Fix: Repair Install and Keep Data (and User Profile). Then install Apps.  That will fix it.